# SerializedProperty to UnityEvent in a Custom Editor

Tags: unity, c#, editors

I am making a Custom Editor for a type that includes a UnityEvent property.

I'm currently facing an issue in converting a SerializedProperty to get that UnityEvent.

Here is how I declare the event in the type I want to edit with this custom editor:

```
public class SomeComponent : MonoBehaviour {

    public UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent EventToAdd;

    //...
}
```

And this is my Editor script

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(SomeComponent))]
public SomeComponentEditor : Editor {

    private SerializedProperty _Events;
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _Events = serializedObject.FindProperty("EventToAdd");
    }


    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        TwitchTVGui TGUI = (TwitchTVGui)target;

        this.serializedObject.Update();
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("EventToAdd"), true);

        this.serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

And then I need to get the UnityEvent out of the serializedObject _Events somehow

Comment: Have you tried `serializedObject.FindProperty("EventToAdd").objectReferenceValue as UnityEvent`?

Answer (score 1):

Huh, I literally just had this problem and found [this code over here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-can-i-get-an-event-widget-in-my-own-inspectors.270418/#post-1786473), but it basically boils down to needing just this:

```
[Serializable] public class CustomEvent : UnityEvent { }

public CustomEvent myEvent = new CustomEvent();
```

Rename the class and field as  you see fit. If you're going to use the same event in multiple script files, make it its own script, but having a micro-class for each one is fine too (it distinguishes that `OnWidgetDoX` and `OnWidgetDoY` are different events).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to serialize events so that they will show up in the inspector.  You do not need to do that yourself.

Instead, just use [`UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html), and it will be available in the inspector for you.  This is simply a wrapper around standard C#.

```
public UnityEvent MyEvent;
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer.I am currently working on a custom editor for our game designer and for that I am using serializedProperties. I can access strings,ints & co , but not UnityEvent...

Comment: @US3L3SS if you add the above line of code, it will show up in the inspector. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: No I want to get the UnityEvent proberty...